# Get all array keys that is not equal to X

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have several files uploaded with a form that is processed by a PHP script. There are several "categories" that I need to have handles separate ways. In other words, I need some of the files in the $_FILES array to be stored someplace, and some others stored in other places.

So what I need is all files (array keys) that are **not $_FILES['filename_form']** to be stored / used separably.

The reason why I need this is because the amount of files being uploaded are dynamic, but always either **$_FILES['filename_type1']** or **$_FILES['filename_type2_*]** where * is a number that increments when more files are input from the form (dynamically)

Might be a very simple solution, either I'm too tired or maybe I've been staring too much at the code, but all I know is I need a solution before tomorrow morning, so it's time sensitive =P

Appreciate all the help I can get.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$files = array();
$filenames = array();
foreach($_FILES as $name => $fileInfo)
{
    if($name != 'filename_form')
    {
        $files[$name] = $fileInfo;
        $filenames[] = $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would change `$val` to `$fileInfo` probably and I would guess, that it is better not to compare strings with `!==`, just `!=` would be enough.

Comment: Those aren't bad suggestions and I put them in my post.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
foreach ( $_FILES as $key => $value )
   if ( preg_match ( '/type2/', $key ) )
      // do something with the type2
   else if ( preg_match ( '/type1/', $key ) )
      // do something with these
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
  $a = explode('_', $key);
  $defaultDir = 'myDefaultDirOrPathOrWhatever';
  if ($a[1] == 'type2') {
    $defaultDir = 'myOtherDirWhenMultipleFiles';
    $incrementPassed = $a[2];
  }
  if (isset($incrementPassed)) unset($incrementPassed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way

```
$keys = array_keys($thearray);
$filteredArray = array_filter($keys, 'fiterKeys');

function filterKeys($item) {
    if($item != 'valuetocheck') return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$type1_files = array(); // Array of files of first type
$type2_files = array(); // Array of files of second type
$underfined_files = array(); // Array of files of unnormal type (who knows :-P)

foreach($_FILES as $name => $value){
    if($name == 'type1'){
        $type1_files[] = $value;
    }
    elseif($name == 'type2'){
        $type2_files[] = $value;
    }
    else{
        $undefined_files[] = $value;
    }
}
```

After foreach you'll have your files devided into arrays, which you can process later as you wish

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES as $filename => $fileinfo) {
  if (strpos($filename, 'form') !== false) {
    $files[$name] = $fileinfo;
    unset($_FILES[$name]);
  }
}

?>
```

Fastest method I can think of, should be faster then any of the previous answers.